# Kubuntu : Kde system panel keeps moving

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on my system and the KDE bottom system panel keeps moving and its very irritating. I don't know why that's happening. It happens only on 1st monitor. I have tried removing and adding it back again, but nothing helps. As this is a movement, I had to make a video and upload it on youtube. Here is the link : [Youtube link](https://youtu.be/XjlaQoOEN3A)

Notice the bottom right part, how it keeps moving.

Comment: Does it do that when there are only a couple of applications open? Could it be the text in an application "button" changing? Do you have a flexible spacer next to your tray, perhaps remove it?